# Как убрать расстояние между картинками?

Tags: html

Как уменьшить расстояние между дивами? чтоб было, как на картинке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.col-4{
   width: 25%;
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-second">
   <div>
      <h2 style="text-align: center;">Photo</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row-2"></div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
   </div>
</div>

</section>
```

Comment: Кажется мне этот вопрос много раз задавался на форумах и в том числе тут. Уберите бордюр (он стоит по умолчанию в 1) и всё. Проверьте margin и padding.

Comment: У вас ошибка синтаксиса: Вы `row-2` сразу же закрыли

Answer (score 2):

`.col-4` добавить:

- `padding: 10px;` - таким образом будут регулироваться отступы
- `box-sizing: border-box;` - так мы зададим другую блочную модель, чтобы ширина и высота не увеличивалась за счет добавленного `padding`

`.col-4 img` добавить:

- `max-width: 100%;` - чтобы картинка не вылазила за пределы блока
- `display: block;` - чтобы она стала блочной.

```css
.col-4 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-4 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-second">
  <div>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Photo</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people">
  </div>
  </div>

</section>
```